convergence of Poisson equations
Let $E$ be a locally compact separable metric space and $B(E)$ be a Banach space of bounded measurable functions on $E$.  For each $n \in \mathbb{N} $, $L^n$ and $L$ are linear operators on $B(E)$ with a common domain $D(L)$. Let $f^n, f \in D(L)$ be such that $f^n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets. Moreover, for any $g \in D(L)$, suppose that $L^ng \to Lg$ uniformly on compact sets. For each $n$, let $h^n$ be the unique solution to the Poisson equation
$$
-L^nh^n = f^n.
$$
(Uniqueness is ensured by requiring $h^n$ and $f^n$ to be centered.) What can I say about the convergence of $h^n$? Ideally, I would want $h^n \to h$ uniformly on compact sets where $h$ is the unique solution to the Poisson equation $-Lh = f$. Where can I look for conditions that would ensure this?
